# How to set smart Morris.js line chart y boundaries?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, morris.js

I recently started a dashboard project and part of it is showing charts. I have been learning Morris.js for the charts and I got to the point where I am properly retrieving JSON data from my `localserver` and creating a chart.

The problem is that the y-axis is too wide. All the points plotted fall in about a third of the chart height. I am aware that I can manually set the `ymax` and `ymin` when creating the chart, but this would require that I loop through all the objects to find the highest and lowest data point. While I am not opposed to do that, I am very new to JavaScript and I'm not sure about the specific syntax. Preferably, I would like to change a setting in Morris so it sets the `ymax` and `ymin` to something reasonable.

Here is an image of the plot and JSON received:
[image]

And in case it matters, my code for creating the chart:

```
new Morris.Line({
    element: 'chart',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: ['csi', 'econtrack', 'gurtam', 'pointer'],
    labels: ['csi', 'econtrack', 'gurtam', 'pointer'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find nothing else to manage the y-axis in Morris so I built my own function to find min and max:

```
function min_and_max(json_data) {
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    for (var data_key in json_data) {
        var entry = json_data[data_key]
        for(var key in entry) {
            var x = entry[key];
            if (!isNaN(x)) { // to avoid using date object
                if (x < min) {min = x;}
                else if (x > max) {max = x;}
            }
        }
    }
    return {'min': min, 'max': max};
}
```

So I could use it when creating the chart like:

```
var limits = min_and_max(data);
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
keys = keys.filter(function(e){return e!=='date'});
new Morris.Line({
    element: element,
    data: data,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: keys,
    labels: keys,
    ymin: limits['min'],
    ymax: limits['max'],
    hideHover: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ymin:'auto'` configuration option :

```
new Morris.Line({
    element: 'chart',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: ['csi', 'econtrack', 'gurtam', 'pointer'],
    labels: ['csi', 'econtrack', 'gurtam', 'pointer'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    ymin:'auto'
});
```

Check [morris.js](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) documentation for more information.